# Request headers are missing on Spring Boot request interceptors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, axios

There is a project developed on Spring framework (backend) and React (frontend).
Basic idea is **to trace requests on server side** if custom (defined by ourself) headers are present on each request.

Problem is when **MultipartFile** is received using `@RequestPart` on Spring custom headers are missing. From frontend custom headers are being send (Checked by DevTools of web browser).

Backend and Frontend code are as follows:

Spring Boot Code:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/url", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public CommandResponse registerCommand(@RequestPart("command") RegisterCommand command, @RequestPart(value="files", required = false)  List<MultipartFile> files) {
        //
        command.validate();
        String responseId = logicFlow.registerComand(command.getId(), command.getMessage(), files);
        command.setResponse(responseId);
        return command.getResponse();
    }
```

React Code:

```
const registerCommand = (variables: { id: string, message: Message, files?: File[] }) => {
  //
  const form = new FormData();
  const command = <RegisterCommand>{ ...variables };

  const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(command)], {
    type: 'application/json',
  });

  if (variables.files) {
    for (const file of variables.files) {
      form.append('files', file);
    }
  }

 form.set('command', blob);

  return axios.post<CommandResponse>(
    url(`/url`),
    form);
};
```

And each axios request is intercepted and headers are added.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
    config => {
      const key = 'dock.context';
      const value = window ? window.sessionStorage.getItem(key) ?? window.localStorage.getItem(key) : '';
      if (!value) {
        return config;
      }

      const context = JSON.parse(value);
      config.headers['X-Trail-Scene-url'] = window.location.href;
      config.headers['X-Trail-Endpoint'] = config.url;
      config.headers['X-Trail-Actor-Id'] = context?.actor?.id || '0@0:0:0:0-0';
      config.headers['X-Trail-Cs-Time'] = Date.now();
      config.headers['X-Trail-Location'] = geoLocation;

      return config
    },
    error => {
      Promise.reject(error)
    }
  )
```

Those headers are being sent from frontend. But when request is checked on backend, those headers are missing. Only 2 headers are present as shown Image 2.

[image]

[image]

I have changed front end part but I didn't work well. But when I remove MultipartFile from input parameters and

````
consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}
``` from backend it works.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@RequestPart` is an [annotation to ask for a part of the multipart request](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestPart.html). It seems that you can just put `@RequestHeader(name="X-Your-Header")` in the controller method parameters for headers you expect, or if you do not want to restrict yourself, then you can just use `java.util.Map` as a method parameter with the same annotation:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/url", consumes = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public CommandResponse registerCommand(
    @RequestPart("command") RegisterCommand command,
    @RequestPart(value="files", required = false) List<MultipartFile> files,
    @RequestHeader Map<String, Object> requestHeaders
) {
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

In this case, you'll get all headers of the HTTP request in this `Map`.

Another option would be to use `HttpServletRequest` directly as a parameter here and then get headers via `getHeaderNames()` method, but in this case, it is not necessary since there is an easier approach with `@RequestHeader` annotation

Comment: Thank you @Mikhail2048. I can get headers now. But my interceptors cant extract headers.